# Only one category shows posts - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories, display

I have got problem with wordpress. Only one category show posts... If I assign post to another category, it does not show in content area. What could be wrong?
Here is my content.php file:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="main-post">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="main-post-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );?>')"></div>
</a>
<div class="main-post-info">
    <a class="post-author" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')) ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
    <a class="post-date" href="<?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>"><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></a>
</div>
<a class="main-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<p class="main-post-lead"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<a class="button button-read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    Czytaj więcej
    <img class="button-arrow" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/button-arrow.png" alt="Czytaj więcej">
</a>
```

Comment: the set of which posts will be displayed depends on what happens _before_ `have_posts()`. Is this all of the file? Which route has been called?

Comment: Yes, this is all of the file. My index.php: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpVPob